# How to create an item in subsite list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How to create an item in subsite list through designer workflow 2010?

Answer (score -1):

You can use workflow condition **Create item in the list**.

Refer this link for more understanding - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-actions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-5a7ad276-0ed7-49b0-b652-e56a77dd96c6